# how to sort "GROUP BY" query result by Frequent values?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

i write php application that it get name of the user browsers:

```
+----------+------------+
| name     | browser    |
+----------+------------+
| Puffball | firefox    |
| Chirpy   | edge       |
| Whistler | chrome     |
| Slim     | firefox    |
| Claws    | edge       |
| Fluffy   | chrome     |
| Fang     | chrome     |
| Bowser   | safari     |
| Buffy    | chrome     |
+----------+------------+
```

i use this sql query to get browsers with "GROUP BY" and the result is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM views WHERE linkid = '$string' GROUP BY browser";

array (size=4)
  0 => string 'firefox'
  1 => string 'edge'
  2 => string 'chrome'
  3 => string 'safari'
```

i want to sort this result by Frequent value, like this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'chrome'
  1 => string 'edge'
  2 => string 'firefox'
  3 => string 'safari'
```

tanx!

Comment: _i use this sql query_ **I see no query** Show us the query you are using, an array is not a query

Comment: At least have decency to ask a proper question.

Comment: tanks @RiggsFolly, now its ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the result ordered by frequency that the browser is mentioned in the input table you need to add a count like this, and then ORDER BY the count column

```
SELECT *, count(browser) as frequency
FROM views 
WHERE linkid = '$string' 
GROUP BY browser
ORDER by frequency
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this below Sql Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` group by browser order by browser asc
```

**Use PHP array Sort**

sort($browser);

Comment: This will not order the results by the frequency of the browser type occuring in the table. It will only oder by the browser name. The PHP sort would be TOTALLY IRRELLEVANT as having grouped on browser you will only get ONE row for each browser